# Maximum number of COM connections with Excel and other MS Office Applications

Tags: python, excel, com

I was wondering what, if any, is the maximum number of Excel COM connections is?

Comment: There is no set maximum. Any limitation would be due to running out of resources. It also depends on what do you mean with "connection". There is no such thing as "connection" in COM per-se but object references (not 100% true but close enough). You can have hundreds of references to Range objects. I've never heard of anybody creating more than a short handful of Excel.Application objects and in most cases you should need only one. You probably cannot open hundreds of spreadsheets without bringing Excel itself to its knees.